# Why do garage remotes revert to billion code?

Tags: garage-door-opener

According to the [LiftMaster troubleshooting guide](http://chamberlain.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4104/~/why-wont-both-my-remotes-work-with-my-opener-at-the-same-time%3F), one common problem is that a Security+ remote reverts to billion code technology.  What causes this, and is there any fix?

> **One of the remotes may have reverted to billion code**
>
> If you have two Security+ remotes and only one or the other will program to the opener, one of the remotes has reverted back to billion code technology. To figure out which one has, you will either need another remote or a keyless entry.
>
> 1. Clear the memory on the opener. Press and hold the learn button for 6 seconds.
> 2. Program the keyless entry. How to program keyless entry (If no keyless entry is available, program a 3rd remote.)
> 3. Program one of your handheld remotes. If the first remote does not program, try the second remote. How to program remote control
>
> The remote that will not program in with the additional accessory is the defective remote.

Comment: The trouble shooting guide says nothing about the battery, Every time I change the battery in my car key fob I have to go through a bunch of on/off key cycles to reteach both remotes. for this reason If one goes bad I change both and reteach. It may be the same cause for your issue.

Comment: You mean you change the battery of both devices, even though only one died?

Comment: yes because the 2nd one may have a month or 2  left then I have to do it all again. Changing them both I end up having to teach them less often.